# Need to know how to autodelete in hours instead of one day Javascript Parse Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have this cloud code that deletes objects from my parse table every 24 hours. I would like to have this code delete objects every 5 hours instead of 24 hours. Can anyone help me modify this code or guide me to do what I need?

```
Parse.Cloud.job('deleteOldPosts', function(request, status) {

// All access
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

var today = new Date();
var days = 1;
var time = (days * 24 * 3600 * 1000); // OTHER LOGIC FOR HOURS???
var expirationDate = new Date(today.getTime() - (time));

var query = new Parse.Query('Places');
    // All posts have more than 1 day //
    query.lessThan('createdAt', expirationDate);

    query.find().then(function (posts) {
        Parse.Object.destroyAll(posts, {
            success: function() {
                status.success('All posts are removed.');
            },
            error: function(error) {
                status.error('Error, posts are not removed.');
            }
        });
    }, function (error) {});
```

});
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to achieve it you need to subtract 5 hours from your current date so you will need to use the following code:

```
var now = new Date();
var expirationDate = new Date();
expirationDate.setHours(now.getHours() - 5);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! So, with your code; if an item is created Saturday 12am it will delete Sunday 12am minus 5 hours? Which is saturday 7pm. Is this correct? What if I add minus 12 instead of minus 5, autodelete is at 12pm saturday? Thanks for your time!!

Comment: with this code you will be able to query for all items that were created in 5 hours or more

Comment: Amazing! Tested for 1 hour and works! Thank you very much!